# Package not recognized in Play2 controller

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have a Maven Play2 (2.2.1) application.  The main module is packaged as a regular Play2 app and the other is packaged as a JAR, as it just contains utility/common code.  The utilities module uses Java source, as I'm leveraging Hibernate for persistence.  The main module uses Scala.

**The problem**

In my controller (Scala), the packages from the utility module are recognized and I can import objects fine.  My IDE (IntelliJ 13) does not "bark" at me and the autocomplete works, showing me the available objects in a particular package.  However, when I refresh the browser the server complains that it cannot find the package (from utility module).

**Question**

Is there a library/plug-in missing that allows Java and Scala to play nicely?

Comment: How did you add your jar to the Play ?

Comment: The Play app has a dependency on the utility library (via Maven), which is packaged as a JAR.